# Passing Header row index to Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

Apache Commons CSV provides method to pass Header columns with `withHeaders()`. But is there a way to pass a specific row index as header row to Apache Commons. I have gone through the docs but have not found anything.

Comment: My read of the documentation is the same as yours. It looks like it is meant for reading single-table-csvs. I'm curious why you would need to read a different row other than the first one as the headers, though.

Answer (score 0):

I came across needing this kind of feature, but Apache Commons CSV doesn't have that. But however, I achieved it by removing all the garbage rows before the header row, so that the header becomes the first row.